# How to use JQuery modal dialog inside asp.net UpdatePanel to focus Close button

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have following JQuery modal dialog in side `UpdatePanel`. When i trigger this dialog from asp.net control event the dialog `Close` button get focused. But if i trigger jquery from server side code (C#) when JQuery dialog appears, its `Close` button does not get focused.

If i disable `UpdatePanel`then JQuery `Close` button get focused when dialog appear. But i do not want to disable `UpdatePanel`.

**JQuery modal dialog**

```
<script>
  function MessageBox(message) {
    $(function () {
        $("#modal_dialog").html(message);
        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            title: "Info",
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: 400,
            modal: true,

            open: function () {
                $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)').focus();
            },
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    });
 }
</script>
```

**Server Side C# code**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "p1", "<script>MessageBox('Password Matched');</script>", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you are as a general rule free to set the focus. I would delay the open, and then open the dialog and then set the focus.

Say like this:

```
function MessageBox(message) {
$(function () {
    var myDlg = $('modal_dialog');

    myDlg.html(message);
    myDlg.dialog({
        title: "Info",
        resizable: false,
        height: "auto",
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
   });
   
   myDlg.dialog('open');
   myDlg.parent('div').find('button:contains("cancel")').focus();

    return true;
});
```

I mean, keep in mind that the dialog code does not wait - so it will always return that last line "true" that you have. But I would delay the dialog open. Then open it, and then try setting focus as per above.

And for some REALLY but REALLY beyond strange reason? I don't see the cancel button in your markup that we supposed to set focus to? Perhaps you mean the ok button you have?

Then this should work:

```
   myDialog.parent('div').find('button:contains("ok")').focus();
```

Comment: Albert D. Kallal thanks for yourvaluable comments. but problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

I sort out the solution by adding 5 microseconds delay

```
setTimeout(function ())
{
   //required function

}, 5);
```

Here is the final code

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
        function MessageBox(message) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(function () {
    
                    $("#modal_dialog").html(message);
                    $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                        title: "Info",
                        resizable: false,
                        height: "auto",
                        width: 400,
                        modal: true,
    
                        open: function () {
                            $(this).parents('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:eq(0)').focus();
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                });
    
            }, 5);
        }
    </script>
```